# Limit Checkboxes to Only Three Checkboxes - How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox, zurb-foundation

I have many checkboxes on a form. I need to limit the total to three checkboxes selected and no more. I had code that worked but I just upgraded my forms to Foundation Custom Forms and my script no longer works and I cannot get it to work.

How do I re-write the script to work?

Here is the current script:

```
$(function(){
  var max = 3;
  var checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

  checkboxes.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var set = $this.add($this.prevUntil('label')).add($this.nextUntil('label'));
    var current = set.filter(':checked').length;
    return current <= max;
  });
});
```

Here is the form code:

```
<label>Effects <span class="red">required</span></label>
   <label for="CAT_Custom_365571_0"><input type="checkbox" value="Creative" id="CAT_Custom_365571_0" name="CAT_Custom_365571" style="display: none;">
<span class="custom checkbox"></span> Creative</label>
   <label for="CAT_Custom_365571_1"><input type="checkbox" value="Euphoric" id="CAT_Custom_365571_1" name="CAT_Custom_365571" style="display: none;">
<span class="custom checkbox"></span> Euphoric</label>
   <label for="CAT_Custom_365571_2"><input type="checkbox" value="Uplifted" id="CAT_Custom_365571_2" name="CAT_Custom_365571" style="display: none;">
<span class="custom checkbox"></span> Uplifted</label>
   <label for="CAT_Custom_365571_3"><input type="checkbox" value="Energetic" id="CAT_Custom_365571_3" name="CAT_Custom_365571" style="display: none;">
<span class="custom checkbox"></span> Energetic</label>
   <label for="CAT_Custom_365571_4"><input type="checkbox" value="Lazy" id="CAT_Custom_365571_4" name="CAT_Custom_365571" style="display: none;">
<span class="custom checkbox"></span> Lazy</label>
   <label for="CAT_Custom_365571_5"><input type="checkbox" value="Focused" id="CAT_Custom_365571_5" name="CAT_Custom_365571" style="display: none;">
<span class="custom checkbox"></span> Focused</label>
<!-- MORE CHECKBOXES -->
```

Obviously when I changed the forms I broke the script. How do I fix this?

Comment: You just have to find how many are selected on the click event. Basically you have to use a different selector relative to the checkbox. Grab the parent of the clicked checkbox then the siblings and then children of those siblings to count how many are checked.

Comment: If they're inside a single element (say with `id='foo'`) you could do: `document.querySelectorAll('#foo input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 3` and you're done. In jQuery maybe `$('#foo input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 3`. If there's more than 3 checked, show a message so the user can fix it.

Comment: If the checkboxes are not actually clicked by the user but a script setting the state then you can't do much because the `click` function on the checkbox will not get triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cx4RJ/2)

```
var $checkboxes = $('input[id^="CAT_Custom_365571"]');
var max = 3;
$checkboxes.show();
$checkboxes.change(function () {
    $(this).prop('checked', function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            return ($checkboxes.filter(':checked').length <= max) ? true : false;
        }
    });
});
```

you can change in above code

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cx4RJ/3)

```
var $checkboxes = $('input[name="CAT_Custom_365571"]');
```

---

References

[Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. It breaks the Foundation Forms for some reason.

Comment: FYI your fiddle won't let a user de-select a checkbox once you've reached 3 checked. Give it a try

Comment: No errors - Here is a screenshot of what happens: http://screencast.com/t/omBi7cLgV0s

Answer (score 2):

I would consider wrapping (if you haven't already) the checkboxes and using a delegate for performance.

Assuming that the elements have been wrapped by an element with id `wrap`:

```
$(function () {
    var max = 3;
    $('#wrap').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
        return $(this).closest('#wrap').find(':checked').length <= max;
    });
});
```

Here's a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pm8m7/1/)**.

Comment: Doesn't work. I believe it has to do with how [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/custom-forms.html) handles the checkboxes because I am technically not checking a checkbox but a CSS element (I believe that is correct).